# Can we connect to Redshift from Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, amazon-redshift, ado

May I ask can we make ADO or any connection to Redshift by Excel VBA?
So far, we connect to SQL Server and get the job results as follows;

-- Current Code for SQL Server 2012/2016

```
Sub Get_DB_Conncetion(StrDBName As String, StrSQL As String, DestSht As String, DestCell As String)

    On Error GoTo Err_DBConnectOpen

    Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim conStr As String
    Dim rs As Variant
    Dim cmd As Object

   'Connect String
    conStr = "Provider=Sqloledb;Data Source=" & StrSvr _
    & ";Initial Catalog=" & StrDBName _
    & ";Connect Timeout=10" _
    & ";user id=" & StrID _
    & ";password=" & StrPWD _
    & ""

    Debug.Print Now & "：Connect String：" & conStr

    'Connect to Database
    con.Open conStr

    'Execute SQL
    con.CommandTimeout = 900

    Set rs = con.Execute(StrSQL)
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        With Sheets(DestSht)
            .Activate
            .Range(DestCell).CopyFromRecordset rs
        End With
    End If


    'Close Session
    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing

    Exit Sub

    'Error Handling
Err_DBConnectOpen:

    MsgBox "Can't Connect" & vbCrLf & _
        Err.Description, vbOKOnly, vbCritical

    EXIT_FLG = True

    'Close Connection
    If con.State <> ADODB.adStateClosed Then
        con.Close
    End If
    Set con = Nothing
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Until we can make confirmed everything's OK, we need to check and compair the figures both of SQL Server and Redshift everyday. For efficiency and accuracy, we'd like to throw the check queries and get the results automatically as much as possible.

Any advice would be appreciated again.
Thank you.

Comment: If you download Amazon's Redshift drivers, you can simply build the connection string to Redshift. The connection string would look something like: `connString = "Driver={Amazon Redshift (x64)};Server=ServerName;Database=DBName;UID=Login;PWD=password;Port=PortNum;SSL=true;Sslmode=Require"`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @ArcherBird !! I'm so glad to know it's possible, since it's a bit burden for me to check 200 tables figures on each database :) Thank you so much for your kind answer.